# How can I make a delete node function?

Tags: c

I've been creating a node_add function, that works properly to me,
but I'm having a hard time creating a node_delete one.

Here is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct friend // The struct
{
   char *name; 
   int age;
   char gender; 
   struct friend* next; // A pointer that points to the next node in the linked list
}friend;
void node_delete(); // The deleting node function
friend* head; // Definging the head of the linked list
void node_delete() // Deleting a node
{
 char name[256];
 printf ("Please enter the friend's name you want to delete: \n");
 fgets (name, 256, stdin);
 fgets (name, 256, stdin); // Getting the name of the person that the user wants to delete
 while (head -> next != NULL) // As long the node isnt the last one
 {
       if (0 == (strcmp(head -> name, name))) // If the name that the user entered matchs a name in the linked list,
       { // It'll skip it
             head -> next = head -> next -> next; // Deletes a node from the linked list
       }
       head -> next; // Going to the next node
}
 free(head); // Freeing the deleted node
}
```

I only have a problem in the delete node function

Comment: It would certainly help if you could give us only the part of code making problems. Furthermore, describing what your actual problem is might also be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (head) {
  if (strcmp(head->name, name) == 0) {
    to_free = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(to_free);
  } else {
    list = head;
    while (list->next) {
      if (strcmp(list->next->name, name) == 0) {
        to_free = list->next;
        list->next = list->next->next;
        free(to_free);
        break; // if only one
      }
      list = list->next;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: jdizzle's answer and mine are doing the same, but mine is more 'explicit' whilst jdizzle's goes much deeper into C-coding-fundamentals.

Comment: As I said in the other solution, what do I put inside the head?
I've had pretty trouble in it... I mean when I do friend* head, what do I put inside the head ?

Comment: hmm, i do not grok your question. you have a linked list: a variable called head, that points to the first element of the list, and the linkage is done by the ->next pointer. if you traverse the linked list, you get yourself a new pointer (like list or tmp) and initially point it to the same as head does, and traverse it by following the ->next. now you have three cases, if you want to delete: your list is empty=> nothing to do; your first element (the one which head points to) is the match, so your (one and only) head-pointer has to point to the next element in list; or you remove middle one

Answer (score 1):

```
struct friend **tmp = &head;
while (*tmp != NULL && (0 != (strcmp((*tmp)->name, name)))) {
  tmp = &((*tmp)->next);
}
if (*tmp) {
  struct friend *freeme = (*tmp);
  (*tmp) = (*tmp)->next;
  free(freeme);
}
```

Comment: you forget the free(); and do you really believe, the original poster groks this?

Comment: If he stares long enough to understand it, it will open a whole new world to him.

Comment: you are right :-) nice point of view.

Comment: In the first line, u wrote **tmp = &head...
though, I didnt know how to define head... or what to put inside...
Also, why do I need a double **? a pointer to the pointer?

Comment: you knoweth and you grok the concept of pointers? a pointer is a variable that points to something (normally a point in space). that is the asterix. A pointer to a pointer is called indirection.

Comment: You globally define head in the code of your question, i'm using that.  head is a pointer to the first element in the list.  If head == NULL then the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

look at this a little bit closer.

```
while (head -> next != NULL) // As long the node isnt the last one
 {
       if (0 == (strcmp(head -> name, name))) // If the name that the user entered matchs a name in the linked list,
       { // It'll skip it
             head -> next = head -> next -> next; // Deletes a node from the linked list
       }
       head -> next; // Going to the next node
}
```

it does not actually traverse the linked list

```
  head -> next; // Going to the next node
```

you should probably make head = head -> next

also, if "head" is the only thing holding on to the front of the linked list, making head = head->next will cause you to loose part of the list. I recommend creating a temporary pointer so temp = head. Then traverse the temp pointer.

Comment: Caution: The node that is removed from the linked list currently is `head->next`, while `head` should be deleted. Thus, you should probably reformulate your condition.

Comment: I understand what u said, though I have 1 problem....
I dont know how to define head..
How can I make the head, to point to the head of the linked list ?