# Whats the mistake here? deleting a node, linked list,

Tags: c

I wrote this code,and I'd like to know whats my problem, if u can help me fix my code insted of writting one of ur own, it'd help me a lot...
Edit: I've changed it to this, and now it doesnt give me a run time error, but when I print the name, or check if the node exists, it says it is...

```
void node_delete(friend *amit) // Deleting a node
{
 friend* temp;
 int flag = 0;
 while (head != NULL) // As long the node isnt the last one
 {
       if (0 == (strcmp(head -> next -> name, amit -> name))) // If the name that the user entered matchs a name in the linked list,
       { // It'll skip it
            temp = head -> next;
             head -> next = head -> next -> next; // Deletes a node from the linked list
             flag = 1;
       }
       if (flag == 1) break;
       head = head -> next; // Going to the next node
}
 free(temp); // Freeing the deleted node
 printf ("%s\n", amit -> name);
}
```

and in the main :

```
amit.name = "amit"
amit.age = 16
amit.gender = 'm'
node_delete(&amit);
```

and the struct define:

```
typedef struct friend // The struct
 {
   char *name; 
   int age;
   char gender; 
   struct friend* next; // A pointer that points to the next node in the linked list
}friend;
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The problem is IMHO that you have too many variables floating around, and your program becomes a juggle act to keep them all up to date. Also: you are only comparing the name; it would be much easyer if the delete function took a string as its argument.

Comment: What do you mean?
like insted of senting &amit, sent only the amit -> name ?

Comment: It isn't clear what the function is supposed to do.  In some ways it appears like it is supposed to be deleting the node pointed to by amit, and in other ways it seems like it is supposed to be deleting all nodes that have a name that is the same as amit->name.

Comment: I wanted to delete the node I'm putting in the parameters, whcih is amit...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a delete node function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459332/how-can-i-make-a-delete-node-function)

Comment: Why are you comparing strings?

Comment: Creating a linked list, with insertion/removal at arbitrary points, is about 10 times harder than you expect it to be.  You need to think it out *very* carefully, and even then you'll usually have bugs.  I've been in the biz 40 years, and I wouldn't expect to get it right the first time.  (But your code above delete all nodes (because it updates `head`) on every search.)

Comment: Hint:  When deleting a node from a linked list there are 3 distinct cases: 1) Deleting the first element.  2) Deleting the last element.  3) Deleting some other element.  You must handle all three cases, and quite often each requires a unique code path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some comments for the first few lines:

```
 head = amit;
 head -> next = amit;  // same as amit->next = amit;
 amit -> next = NULL;  // same as head->next = null;
 while (head -> next != NULL) // will never do anything since head->next is null
```

Comment: Didnt though about it... so how can I fix it ?

Comment: sorry, same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459332/how-can-i-make-a-delete-node-function . my answer: take a book and learn the concept of pointers and linked lists (it all is explained in the bible: K&R Programming in C)

Comment: haha, I did read in the internet, though every time I'm going through a new subject, I'm having a hard time for the first few times till I get the "catch"...

Comment: yes, okay. BUT you seem to have a problem with "basics" instead of the very special case of linked lists. You not even seam to grok "pointers", so it is fruitless to tell you about linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
void node_delete(char *name)
{
 friend *tmp, **p;

 for (pp = &root; (tmp = *pp) ; pp = &tmp->next) 
 {
     if (strcmp(tmp->name, name)) continue; // No match: walk on
     printf("Deleted %s\n", tmp->name);
     *pp = temp->next;
     free(tmp);
     break;
 }    
}
```

(assuming a global root pointer to the head of the linked list)
To be called like:

```
node_delete("Amit");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
friend *head = NULL;

...

add(data) {
  friend *next = malloc(sizeof(bla));
  fill(next, data);

  if (head == NULL) 
    head = next; 
  else {
    next->next = head;
    head = next;
  }
}

del(data) {
  if (head) {
    if (your_check(head, data)) {
       to_free = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(to_free);
    } else {
      friend *list = head;
      while (list->next) {
        if (your_check(list->next, data)) {
          to_free = list->next;
          list->next = list->next->next;
          free(to_free);
        }
        list = list->next;
      }
    }
  }
}
```